# Follow symlinked directories in Dired

Tags: dired, symbolic-links

On a Linux machine  I symlink some directories into my home directory like this:

```
/home/mrdarcy:
total used in directory 231 available 520120
drwxrwxr-x  3     4k 04-30 18:16 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2     4k 2017-08-23  Desktop
lrwxrwxrwx  1     30 2017-10-10  devel -> /working/mrdarcy/devel
.
.
.
```

(because `/working` is the mount point of a much bigger disk).

When I view my home director in Dired and I am on the `devel` line I would like to open the symlinked directory. However the command I know of, `dired-find-file`, opens it as **`/home`**`/mrdarcy/devel`.

How can I follow the symlink with a Dired command and open **`/working`**`/mrdarcy/devel`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the value of `find-file-visit-truename` to `t` — for instance with customise via `M-x customize-variable RET find-file-visit-truename` or just with `(setq find-file-visit-truename t)`.

This will result in `dired-find-file` and Emacs in general, always following symlinks when opening a file or directory. (See the documentation of `find-file-visit-truename` with `C-h v find-file-visit-truename` for details.)

If you'd prefer to have a separate function that opens the given directory, following symlinks, the following should do what you want:

```
(defun dired-find-file-following-symlinks ()
  "In Dired, visit the file or directory on the line, following symlinks"
  (interactive)
  (let ((find-file-visit-truename t))
    (dired-find-file)))
```